# js Search String and get matched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search, match

I want to ask what is the best way to search string and get matched element?

```
//I want to get similar or matched element and the index of it.
//Search key ward 
var key = 'Pap';
```

```
<ul>
 <li>Papa</li>
 <li>Mama</li>
</ul>
```

My Idea now is use `$.each` and match its text of each, but I believe that should be a wrong way. However, I couldn't find any references from net about this question.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:contains` selector

```
$('*:contains("'+key+'"):last')
```

To find exact match will the whole text in element use this

```
$.fn.exactMatch = function (key) {
    var p = $(this).find(':contains("' + key + '"):last');
    if (p.text() == key) {
        p.css('background', 'yellow');
    } else {
        //Not exact match function if wanted
    }
}
```

To use this function do this

```
$(el).exactMatch(key);
```

Comment: The `:last` seems redundant, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: When you use contains you get all the parents of the element you want to select, so i use last to get the exact element that contains "key"

Comment: I tired $(el.selector + ':contains("'+ key +'"):last') and $(el).find('*:contains("'+ key +'"):last'), both didnt work, What am I missing?

Comment: the el here means the ul element

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me, are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: no there is no error in console, may I ask the '*' here, is it mean the whole document?? if I only want to search inside of ul, how should I write it?

Comment: @Anton May I ask if I want exactly matched element, how can I implement the sentence?

Comment: If you mean var key = "Hello world" then yes, but the key has to be exactly matched to the elements string

Comment: @Anton Sorry I dont really understand. On your jsfiddle, key = Pap or Papa can change the color.

Comment: Yea that works because Pap exists, but if you change the key to "papa" it wont find it

Comment: how can I do if not Papa, not match the whole text, not change the color?

Comment: Thank you very much, since I found that  E[foo='bar'] selector may not work on jquery....